# Program ending abruptly - C

Tags: c

I have written the following code to perform Queue functions where elements of two arrays are Enqueued alternately. However this program ends abruptly after calling Display or Dequeue function. Can anyone help me know why?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define MAX 10

typedef struct{
    int front;
    int rear;
    int elements[MAX];
}queue;
int isfull(queue *);
int isempty(queue *);
void create(queue *);
void enqueue(queue *,int);
void dequeue(queue *);
void display(queue *);
int main()
{
    int a[100],b[100],x,y,i,m,k,c=0;
    int p=0,q=0;
    char s;
    scanf("%d%d",&x,&y);
    for(i=0;i<x;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }
    for(i=0;i<y;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&b[i]);
    }
    scanf("%d",&m);
    queue Q;
    Q.front=-1;
    Q.rear=-1;
    for(i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
        
        scanf("%c",&s);
        switch(s)
        {
            case 'J':
                if(isfull(&Q))
                    printf("FULL\n");
             else
             {
                
                if(p>=x && q>=y)
            {
                printf("EMPTY\n");
            }
            else
            {
                c++;
                if(c%2!=0)
                {
                    k=a[p];
                    p++;
                }
                else
                {
                    k=b[q];
                    q++;
                }
                enqueue(&Q,k);
                
            }
             }
                break;
            case 'V':
                if(isempty(&Q))
                {
                    printf("EMPTY\n");
                }
                else
                {
                    dequeue(&Q);
                }
                
                break;
            case 'D':display(&Q);
                break;
        }
    }
}
int isfull(queue *pq)
{
    if((pq->front==0)&&(pq->rear==MAX-1))
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
int isempty(queue *pq)
{
    if(pq->front==-1)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}

void enqueue(queue *q,int element)
{
    if(q->front==-1)
    {
        q->front=q->rear=0;
    }
    else
    {
        q->rear++;
    }
    q->elements[q->rear]=element;
    
}
void dequeue(queue *q)
{
    int temp;
    temp=q->elements[q->front];
    if(q->front==q->rear)
    {
        q->front=q->rear=-1;
    }
    else
    {
        q->front++;
    }
}

void display(queue *q)
{
    int i;
    for(i=q->front;i<=q->rear;i++)
        printf("%d ",q->elements[i]);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Input :

```
5 /*No. of elements in array1*/
6 /*No. of elements in array2*/
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4 5 6 /*Array elements*/
8 /*No. of commands*/
J
J
J
D
V
V
J
D

J  Enqueue
V  Dequeue 
D  Display
```

**The expected output is as follows :**

```
1 1 2
2 2
```

**The output I am getting is :**

```
1 1 2
```

(exit)

Basically it does display once but the program ends after displaying whereas it should wait for another command.

This is my first time here. So please excuse, if I havent formatted it properly.

Comment: I just ran your program and see that it prints some output and exits with code 0. Please [edit] your question and show the output you get and the output you would expect, and if necessary explain what's wrong with the actual output. Describing what the program is supposed to do might also help us to understand the program.

Comment: You need to use debugger to find out why. Run program under debugger, see where it stops, analyze code, variable values, etc.

Comment: You may need to change `scanf("%c", &s);` to `scanf(" %c", &s);` (note the space before the `%c`) to skip the newlines between the queue commands in the input.

Comment: @Bodo Thank you for replying and I have edited it. Also the program worked on changing scanf("%c", &s); to scanf(" %c", &s);